# Collate pivot columns into single column and change format SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a complex query that ends like this:

```
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Name]) 
    FOR [Name] In([Category1], [Category2], [Category3]) 
) As pt
```

The pivot function combines multiple row data into a single row. Some of these fields are null and some have the category flag. How do I output a single column that is true if any of these columns have a value or false if all the values are null? The values are text or null. Extra, how do I suppress or hide the columns in the output? I am seeking MSSQL SQL compatible answer.

Answer (score 2):

You add that logic into the `select clause` above the pivot

```
SELECT
 id, [Category1], [Category2], [Category3]
 , case when [Category1] is null and [Category2] is null and [Category3] is null
        then 'False'
        else 'True'
   end your_ol_name
FROM yourtable 
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Name]) 
    FOR [Name] In([Category1], [Category2], [Category3]) 
) As pt
```

Note this same select clause is where you would use ISNULL() or COALESCE() on any column as well. I'm not sure what you intend by "suppress or hide". Perhaps this will aid you:

```
SELECT
  id
  , ISNULL([Category1],'-') Category1
  , ISNULL([Category2],'-') Category2
  , ISNULL([Category3],'-') Category3
  , case when [Category1] is null and [Category2] is null and [Category3] is null
        then 'False'
        else 'True'
   end your_ol_name
FROM yourtable 
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Name]) 
    FOR [Name] In([Category1], [Category2], [Category3]) 
) As pt
```

Comment: Thank you!  Late to this, but this helped me develop a more comprehensive answer to a similar problem, which I'll share as an answer.  +1!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand this, you're looking to pivot, but then also to test the columns which have been created by the pivot for NULL, and flag one field as 1/0 based on the NULL status of all those newly created columns.

Here's a snippet of some code I wrote (thanks, Paul Maxwell!), hope it helps:

```
SELECT isCapturedAll = CASE WHEN [1] IS NULL 
                            OR [2] IS NULL 
                            OR [4] IS NULL 
                            OR [13] IS NULL 
                            OR [93] IS NULL 
                            OR [31] IS NULL
                            OR [30] IS NULL 
                            OR [28] IS NULL
                        THEN 0      ELSE 1      END 
FROM (
        SELECT       rec.RecText 
                    ,rec.RecDtm
                    ,rec.CatalogDimID 
        FROM        Record rec
        INNER JOIN  CatalogDim cat ON cat.CatalogDimID = rec.CatalogDimID
        WHERE       rec.CatalogDimID IN (1,2,4,13,93,31,30,28)
) r
PIVOT
(
    MAX([RecText]) 
    FOR [CatalogDimID] In([1],[2],[4],[13],[93],[31],[30],[28]) 
) As pvt
```

To suppress not-fully-populated records, I would put this whole query into a sub-query and test the flag (WHERE isCapturedAll = 1).